# DIVs and images not showing in Safari, fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm going crazy with this homepage: http://faboola.it

The boxes with the icons/links below the hero image work fine on chrome and FF, but don't render in Safari (desktop, 11.02). I tried removing every animation, replacing SVG with PNG, but doesn't work.

Using Wordpress with WPJoints/Foundation 6.3

Any ideas? Thank you! :)

Comment: well just checked at safari from an iphone and it works...

Comment: Don't downvote, because on safari desktop it doesn't works and i'm still trying to figure why ^^

Comment: I have checked in Safari Desktop and the issue is there. I have up voted it ...

Comment: Yes, sorry it's safari desktop that's driving me nuts! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it has to do with the Motion UI animations on the DIVs. Removing the animation from CSS seems to fix the problem. Looks like a bug in Motion UI on Safari:
https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/54883-mui-series-safari-11-compatibility

https://github.com/zurb/motion-ui/issues/97

I removed the animations. :(